# How to do mouseover using webdriver actions?

Tags: selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to get element that appear after a mouseover action. how to do ?

I tried:

```
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.moveToElement(elem);
action.perform();
WebElement myDynamicElement = (new WebDriverWait(driver,10)).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("class*='hoverEverywhereTooltip'")));
```

this element appear just after the mouse over event.

Comment: Can you post the error you are seeing when running this code?

Comment: it worked I missed [] in my cssSelector properties: WebElement myDynamicElement = (new WebDriverWait(driver,10)).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("[class*='hoverEverywhereTooltip']")));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it worked I missed **[]** in my `cssSelector` properties:

> WebElement myDynamicElement = (new WebDriverWait(driver,10)).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.c‌​ssSelector("[class*='hoverEverywhereTooltip']")));

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

code:

```
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
WebElement menuhover = driver.findElement(By.linkText("Menu"));
actions.moveToElement(menuhover);

WebElement subLink = driver.findElement(By.id("submenu"));
actions.moveToElement(submenu);
actions.click();
actions.perform();
```